# WPF Scaling an Image inside a Canvas

Tags: wpf, mvvm

When I place the following code in a Window or UserControl, the image is displayed with its native width and height.  Is there a way to automatically scale outer canvas to proportions of the containing window while retaining the proper aspect ratio for the window?

```
    <Canvas Background="AliceBlue">
        <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
        </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
        <Image Source="ImageName.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

        <Canvas Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="20" Width="20" Height="20" Background="Salmon"/>
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: Canvas isn't a good container for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Canvas never resizes its child elements. Put the Image control in a Grid instead, then probably put the whole thing in a Viewbox:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid>
        <Image Stretch="None" Source="ImageName.jpg" .../>
        <Canvas Margin="20,20,0,0" Width="20" Height="20" Background="Salmon"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: The complication I neglected to put in my question is the little 20x20 canvas that has to maintain it's position within the image when it is scaled.  This all works when I change the ScaleX and ScaleY properties.

Comment: And the "overlay" 20x20 Canvas should not scale, but only be moved?

Comment: It should scale.  The application is the position of an OCR'd field in an image.

Comment: That works if I put the Height/Width of the image on the canvas but I was hoping there was a way to do it in the framework.

Comment: I meant the outer Grid. See the edit. Replaced Left and Top on the Canvas by a Margin, which could also be done by a RenderTransform.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your Canvas in a [ViewBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for helping... I saw that in another answer.  I tried it and I must be doing something wrong.  The entire window is blank.

Comment: Putting an Image control in a Viewbox doesn't make much sense, because Image is already stretched (depending on how you've set its Stretch property). You should instead put the Image in another Panel, preferrably a Grid.

Comment: It 'kinda' works if I add a Height and Width to the Image but I was hoping the framework could do that for me.